# Why this job is exiting with error code 1

Tags: centos, docker, gitlab, centos8

So ... I'm having a problem running a job inside gitlab. I'm using it as a docker container, which both he and the runner are running on a server with CentOS 8 as the main OS. Below I will put information about the job log and the .gitlab-ci that I am using to try to build the application.

[Job log](https://pastebin.com/HvTS1L1c)

[Runner log](https://pastebin.com/ugxW4NvH)

[.gitlab-ci.yml](https://pastebin.com/GtbQ9EaX)

Docker version: 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d

Gitlab version: 13.4.1 (c90be62bdef)

Runner version: 13.4.1

I don't have much experience with devops and gitlab either, so I don't know exactly what and where to look for a solution to this problem. And thanks in advance for who can help me with this issue.

Comment: `See "/tmp/ng-eoLfoG/angular-errors.log" for further details.` - the referenced log files could be helpful.

Comment: How and where I can see this log ? I've tried to access the gitlab and runner containers, and both of them doesn't have this path to see this log.